# Flutter and Firebase problems when running the first time

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

When I start the flutter project using firebase, it will show something like [a bunch of red unreadable code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJWRk.png)

```
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core_web-0.1.1+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase_core_web\FirebaseCoreWebPlugin.javaʹ�û����ѹ�ʱ�� API��
ע: �й���ϸ��Ϣ, ��ʹ�� -Xlint:deprecation ���±��롣ע: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.4.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FirebaseCorePlugin.javaʹ�û����ѹ�ʱ�� API��
ע: �й���ϸ��Ϣ, ��ʹ�� -Xlint:deprecation ���±��롣
ע: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore_web-0.1.1+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\cloud_firestore_web\FirestoreWebPlugin.javaʹ�û����ѹ�ʱ�� API��
ע: �й���ϸ��Ϣ, ��ʹ�� -Xlint:deprecation ���±��롣
ע: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.14.0+9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.javaʹ�û����ѹ�ʱ�� API��
ע: �й���ϸ��Ϣ, ��ʹ�� -Xlint:deprecation ���±��롣
ע: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.13.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.javaʹ�û����ѹ�ʱ�� API��
ע: �й���ϸ��Ϣ, ��ʹ�� -Xlint:deprecation ���±��롣
ע: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.13.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.javaʹ����δ������ȫ�Ĳ�����
ע: �й���ϸ��Ϣ, ��ʹ�� -Xlint:unchecked ���±��롣
```

But the program can run, and it does not show any problem when hot restart. It only appears when terminate the program and then run it.

I use

```
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
  firebase_core: ^0.4.2+1
```

Answer (score 0):

try running `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub cache repair`